# Random Related Products Static Magento Page

Tags: php, magento, random, content-management-system

I have several "CMS" pages in Magneto; and I need to create a set of 3 links/images at the bottom of each page that are random pulled from a specific category.
For example if you are on "Fishing in Minnesota" page you would see 3 random products from the fishing category displayed at the bottom of the page.
Thanks,
-Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the built-in functionality for adding random products to a CMS page / block has been broken in Magento for awhile now. You may want to try this now that CE 1.7 has been released - it may work:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" category_id="3" num_products="5"}}
```

If not, there's a custom fix at the end of this thread by guys on the Magento forum: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3696/P105/#t365674

Comment: Thanks Corez. The built in function looks like it is still broken and the link on form sort of works; but doesn't filter by category. Any thoughts?